# Псевдоним таблици из запроса

Tags: php, laravel, php7

Имеется вот такой запрос.

Далее хочу всунуть его в unionall

```
 $program_assigment1 = program_assigment::select()->join('program as p', function ($join) {
        $join->on('ps.PRGR_ID','=','p.PRGR_ID')
        ->on('ps.Pr_No','=','p.no');
    })
    ->where('ps.PrGr_ID', '=', 1)();
```

В селекте мне нужно выбрать поля,как присвоить псевдоним `program_assigment1`?

```
$prog = pr::select()->unionAll($program_assigment1)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в `program_assigment::select()` написать так:

```
$program_assigment1 = DB::table('your_table_name AS program_assigment1')
->select()
->.............
```